# Data doesn't change when im edit via active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Data doesn't change when i'm trying to edit category title via active admin

this my admin/category.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Category do


permit_params :list, :of, :attributes, :on, :model,:title

controller do
 def permitted_params
   params.permit post: [:title]
 end
 end

end
```

Comment: Why you doesn't use 'permit_params' which  you typed above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope that below will work for the same.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Category do
permit_params :category, :title
end
```

For overriding params hash you can use like below

```
ActiveAdmin.register Category do
  #...
  controller do
    #...
    def permitted_params
      params.permit(:category => [:name])
      # params.permit! # allow all parameters
    end
  end
end
```